# sending mail from gmail account - Python

Tags: python, email, gmail

could someone kindly tell me, what's wrong with the code below? TIA :)))

```
import smtplib
if raw_input("if you want to send a message from a gmail account, type yes: ") == 'yes':
    try:      
        sender = raw_input("from:\n")
        senders_pwd = raw_input("password:\n")
        recipient = raw_input("to:\n")
        print 'ok, now compile your message:'
        subject = raw_input("subject:\n")
        body = raw_input("your message:\n")
        message = "subject: %s\n%s" %(subject,body)

        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        print "ok, I've sent your email"
    except:
        print 'failed to send'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the sendmail() function. Add something like these three lines after the last server.ehlo():

```
server.login(sender, senders_pwd)
server.sendmail(sender, recipient, message)
server.close()
```